# How to create a service in windows vista example

Tags: java, windows, windows-services

I am trying to create a new windows vista service through sc utility in command run, from some reason what worked in windows xp doesn't work in vista (surprised?). I am running the following command:

sc create rmiregistryService binPath ="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_05\bin\rmiregistry.exe"

and it doesn't work... does anyone have an idea why? Can anyone point me to a working example?

Thanks,
vondip

Comment: When you say, "doesn't work," what do you mean?  What error message are you getting?  Vista should have the "sc" command.

Comment: Did you run it with an administrative privileged command line?

Answer (score 4):

You have a space between binPath and the =

try `sc create rmiregistryService binPath= "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_05\bin\rmiregistry.exe"` instead

Also, make sure you're running as administrator

Answer (score 0):

To get the quote at the beginning of the executable, I had to escape it with `"\"` like so:

```
sc create rmiregistryService binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_05\bin\rmiregistry.exe"
```

Answer (score -1):

This could be because of Security restictions of Vista.

Run This Path on Run Window

**Control Panel\User Accounts and Family Safety\User Accounts**

**Turn User Account Control on or off**

Turn Off This Function

Good Luck